# send output UIDatePicker by email with swift

Tags: ios, swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am really new at programming with swift and trying to build an app that sends a date/time from UIDatePicker to a defined email address. I try to convert the output of UIDatePicker to string. How do I get this in my email?

I get an error on "  mailComposerVC.setMessageBody(strDate"

My code so far is:

```
@IBOutlet weak var mijnDatumTijd: UIDatePicker!
@IBAction func datumTIjd(_ sender: UIDatePicker){let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

    dateFormatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short

    let strDate = dateFormatter.string(from: mijnDatumTijd.date)
}

var email: String = ""
@IBOutlet weak var Identifier: UITextField!
    @IBAction func buttonClick(sender: UIButton) {
        //getting input from Text Field
        email = Identifier.text!
    }

@IBAction func send(_ sender: UIButton) {
    _ = configuredMailComposeViewController()
    }

func configuredMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {
    let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self as? MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate // Extremely important to set the --mailComposeDelegate-- property, NOT the --delegate-- property

    mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["example@email.com"])
    mailComposerVC.setSubject("Sending you an in-app e-mail...")
    mailComposerVC.setMessageBody(strDate, isHTML: false)

    return mailComposerVC
```

Comment: What's the error message? (put it in your question, not in a comment).

Comment: And what is `strDate`?

Answer (score 0):

The error message you are getting (that you don't list, but can be inferred from the line you get the error on) is caused by a scope issue.

Variables cannot be accessed outside the scope they are create in. In Swift you can almost always translate scope as matching curly braces {}.

You create `strDate` in `datumTIjd(_ sender: )` which is a function that traps `strDate` inside its braces. Nothing outside the function even knows `strDate` exists. Since you create `strDate` on the last line of `datumTIjd(_ sender: )` and never use it the compiler may optimize it away (if it doesn't `strDate` only lives for the tiniest of blips in time since everything declared in the function's scope gets deleted when the function is done) and you likely have a warning telling you `strDate` is an unused variable.

When you get to `configuredMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController` your reference `strDate`, however it is not in the local scope or any higher scope.

Lose the `let` from:

```
let strDate = dateFormatter.string(from: mijnDatumTijd.date)
```

making it:

```
strDate = dateFormatter.string(from: mijnDatumTijd.date)
```

Then before the line

```
var email: String = ""
```

add:

```
var strDate: String = ""
```

That will move `strDate` from the scope of the function it currently lives in to the class's scope allowing any method in the class to access it, clearing your current error.

Answer (score 0):

- You are getting this error because of the scope of **strDate** variable is limited inside **datumTIjd** function since it is local variable. So you just need to make it global so that you can access it inside your **configuredMailComposeViewController()** function.
- So just make a change in your code as below:
- Declare **strDate** where you declared email variable as: 
       **`var strDate:String = ""`**
- Now change in your **datumTIjd** action:

Modify this line - **`let strDate = dateFormatter.string(from: mijnDatumTijd.date)`**
as

**`self.strDate = dateFormatter.string(from: mijnDatumTijd.date)`**

Comment: Thank you for your help! the error is now solved. When I try to launch the app I get the next bug. I tried to clean my project but it doesn't help.